# c#, how to Reuse the SqlCommand and OleDbCommand

Tags: c#, sqlcommand, oledbcommand

this is the url i refer to: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317559

i study their method and had applied them, everything is fine until i include 2_2, error msg: No current query in data reader.

I already close my drSelect1_1 under 2_1 if statement. I need to close it or else i cant create a new one. so problem is, how to open the drSelect1_1 again so that i can use for my 2_2? i tried to create drSelect1_1a instead of use back drSelect1_1, got error with: Invalid attempt to access a field before calling Read() . 
any advice? code as below:

```
cmdSelect.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM member WHERE username = @username";

connSelect.Open();

MySqlDataReader drSelect1_1 = cmdSelect.ExecuteReader();

if (drSelect1_1.Read())
{
     //1_1
     this.lbl1_1.Text = drSelect1_1["username"].ToString();

     //2_1
     if (drSelect1_1["direct1"].ToString() != "")
     {
        //this.ib2_1.Visible = true;
        this.lbl2_1.Text = drSelect1_1["direct1"].ToString();
        drSelect1_1.Close();

        cmdSelect.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM member WHERE username = '" + this.lbl2_1.Text + "'";
        MySqlDataReader drSelect2_1 = cmdSelect.ExecuteReader();

        if (drSelect2_1.Read())
        {                  
             drSelect2_1.Close();
        }
    }

    //2_2            
    if (drSelect1_1["direct2"].ToString() != "")
    {

    }
}
connSelect.Close();
```

Comment: What's your reasoning behind wanting to reuse the command? Why not just create another one?

Comment: What happens if an exception is thrown, where do you Dispose your resources?

Comment: @RichardSzalay, my previous code is create a new command and connection. but the page take times to load. because i need to repeat the same step for 32 times. that means the website need to open 32 new connection and close them.

Comment: Why do you want to re-open drSelect1_1, can't you complete all the work i.e. what you're trying to do at 2_2 before you close it in the first place?

Comment: Creating multiple commands that use the same connection object will not open multiple connections

Comment: @SpaceghostAli, i know what u mean, but how? it's a "IF" statement. i need to done the first "IF" before the second "IF"

Comment: If you can't do the work for 2_2 before closing the reader, you'll have to create another instance. What's the actual problem you're trying to solve though? I noticed the 2 command texts are almost identical, maybe there is a better way to approach your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT #2**

Alright, well if that's the case. Assign the values to variables at the beginning of the block, before closing the reader. It will save you from so much trouble. :)

```
if (drSelect1_1.Read())
{
     string username = drSelect1_1["username"].ToString();
     string direct1 = drSelect1_1["direct1"].ToString();
     string direct2 = drSelect1_1["direct2"].ToString();

     drSelect1_1.Close();

     //1_1
     this.lbl1_1.Text = username;

     //2_1
     if (direct1 != "")
     {
        //this.ib2_1.Visible = true;
        this.lbl2_1.Text = direct1;

        cmdSelect.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM member WHERE username = '" + this.lbl2_1.Text + "'";
        MySqlDataReader drSelect2_1 = cmdSelect.ExecuteReader();

        if (drSelect2_1.Read())
        {                  
             drSelect2_1.Close();
        }
    }

    //2_2            
    if (direct2 != "")
    {

    }
}
```

---

You have closed your data reader `drSelect1_1.Close();` and tried accessing it again at

```
if (drSelect1_1["direct2"].ToString() != "")
```

Remove this line

```
drSelect1_1.Close();
```

Or just move before it before the `}` in your `Read()` block.

**EDIT**:

Just create another instance of `MySqlCommand`, do it like this:

```
MySqlCommand cmdSelect2 = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM member WHERE username = '" + this.lbl2_1.Text + "'", connSelect);
MySqlDataReader drSelect2_1 = cmdSelect2.ExecuteReader();
```

So you can safely remove the above mentioned line.

Comment: i cant remove it or i not able to create drSelect2_1

Comment: Just create another instance, please see my answer again.

Comment: @Ruen same,  i still need to close the previous dataReader first :(